# error in adding row names with duplicates

Tags: r

I've read  a big .csv file into R with read.csv() function . my data looks like this

```
> data[1:6,1:4]
        X       AD AD.1 AD.2
1 A   1    0    0
2 B   1    0    1
3 C   0    0    0
4 D   0    0    0
5 D 115  156  193
6 A   0    0    0
```

I want to assign column X as row name. 
I did following things and I've got error.

```
name<-data[,1]
data1<-data[,-1]
row.names(data1)<-name
```

The error I've got is :

> Error in `row.names<-.data.fram duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
>   In addition: Warning message: non-unique values when setting
>   'row.names'

I know that I might have some rows with the same names, but I have to keep them. 
would somebody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need this column as row names? Is it for formatting purposes or for computational purposes?

Comment: @SimonO101 it's for both purposes.

Comment: Ok, show what you are planning to do next and someone might suggest a better way. There's no explicit need to set this column as row names as such.

Comment: basically my row names are the first column ( brain-mir-65,...) and I want to do some computation . when I want to analysis the output of computation, I need explicitly have row name on it (some portrays). but if i don't set my row names, it will be 1,2,3,... and it will make analysis hard.

Comment: Please add a worked example. Otherwise this is all just guesswork. Basically you *have* to have unique `rownames` in a `data.frame` so you're stuck with a solution of making them unique if you persist with this method.